# joomla tooltips on form field validation

Tags: php, validation, joomla, tooltip, jform

I have a Joomla module with a JForm having a few fields. I implemented client side validation for the field as described here: 
https://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation

I can also show a tooltip message for the fields when cursor is hovering above based on the below: 
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_add_tooltips_to_your_Joomla!_website

But I could not figure out yet how to show those tooltips ONLY when the user entered invalid data into the field.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to use a custom class for the tooltip, and only do the javascript init on the form validation.
e.g:

```
<span class="hasTipValidation" 
    title="My Tooltip Title :: Tooltip text for hasTipValidation class.">
    <input name="whatever" type="text" /></span>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ....
    var f = document.adminForm;
    if (!document.formvalidator.isValid(f)) {
        var JTooltips = new Tips($$('.hasTipValidation'), 
       { maxTitleChars: 50, fixed: false});     
    }
    else { 
       ...
    };
    ...
</script>
```

However imo, it's probably not a good idea, it's better to show the error directly before of after the field, without needing the user to hover on the field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Maybe I was not clear in my explanation:  but i want display the tooltip error messages right after the user entered the invalid data (even if the cursor is not hovering above the field). How would that change your proposed solution? Thanks a lot!

Comment: then i think you should rather use popover with 'manual' trigger: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! According to the joomla client side validatation spec: ““Joomla assigns the invalid class to form fields that do not pass the validation test. invalid is also added to the field labels.” How could I catch this “event” of the invalid class added, to be able to display my popover? Thanks!

Comment: you can trigger the popover after the form validation fails. instead of the JTooltips init i did in reply, you can do $(f).find('.invalid').each(function() { // trigger popover here});

Comment: @wanderlusted I haven't tried what I am about to suggest, and it feels a bit hacky, but have a look at MutationObservers: https://davidwalsh.name/mutationobserver-api